# How to compute the integral $I_{\alpha} $?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

Someone has an idea to calculate the following integral

$$I_{\alpha} = \int_{0}^{+\infty} t^{-\alpha} (1-a)^{t} dt; \quad  0<a,\alpha<1.$$
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is $\int_0^\infty e^{-bt}t^{(1-\alpha)-1}dt$ where $b=-\log (1-a)>0$. Substitute $bt=u$ you will get Gamma function.